# How do I save all locally created records in ember / ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Currently, the Ember Data `filter` method has been deprecated. What's the best way to approach saving all new/updated records of a particular type?

You can call `save()` on a `RecordArray` so I have been doing:

`this.get('store').peekAll('record-type').save()` but I'm not sure if there's some better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```js
this.get('store').findAll('users').then((users) => {
  users
    .filterBy('dirtyType', 'created') // filter for unsaved records
    .invoke('save'); // call the save method on each model instance
});
```

If you return the users object you get an array of promises that you could catch with `Ember.RSVP.all()`, to listen for when all the users have been saved.